# Convert XML to xlsx in powershell

Tags: powershell

I found some powershell command online to convert an xlsx file to an xml file. 
This works great, but the xml I am getting will be manipulated slightly, and after that I need to convert it back into a standard xlsx file.

With an xml generated from the below commands, how could I convert it back to an xlsx file?

Thanks!

```
$xlXMLSpreadsheet = 46
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("c:\Test.xlsx")
$WorkBook.SaveAs("c:\Test.xml", $xlXMLSpreadsheet)
$Excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the opposite? ie. switch `test.xlsx` and `test.xml` around

Comment: I got an exception. Maybe something to do with xml spreadsheet being 46? I don't know powershell so don't know what the 46 is referring to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just open the xml file and save it.

The Format code for an xlsx file is 51, as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel

```
$xlsSpreadsheet = 51
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("c:\Test.xml")
$WorkBook.SaveAs("c:\Test.xlsx", $xlsSpreadsheet)
$Excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!