# Powershell export xml content to xslx spreadsheet

Tags: excel, xml, powershell

I'm trying to export all my xml content files, to an spreadsheet formatted with xml schema.
Basicaly is the reverse process of import data from xml in excel.

Open excell >> Developer >> Import >> XmlData

Is there any way with powershell, to export xml to excell with xml schema, or the odder hand import the xmldata from excel ?

My xml sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<opex:OPEXMetadata xmlns:opex="http://www.openpreservationexchange.org/opex/v1.0">
<opex:Transfer>
<opex:SourceID>7c513946-b70b</opex:SourceID>
</opex:Transfer>
<opex:Properties>
<opex:Title>FLEx_backup</opex:Title>
<opex:Description>FLEx_backup</opex:Description>
<opex:SecurityDescriptor>U_UserAccess</opex:SecurityDescriptor>
<opex:Identifiers>
    <opex:Identifier type="code">FLEx_backup</opex:Identifier>
</opex:Identifiers>
</opex:Properties>
</opex:OPEXMetadata>
```

My spreadsheet sample part:

[image]

My code:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Scripts\MetadataExport\Output\0333_OPEX_20201031 | ForEach-Object{
    $Content = @{}
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw)
    [PSCustomObject]$Content | 
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Scripts\MetadataExport\Output\Deposit_Check_Template_OPEX.xlsx
}
```

This code don't gives any error, but also don´t do anything and corrupt my xslx file.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49288014/convert-xml-to-xlsx-in-powershell

Comment: Hi @Doug,tahnks a lot for your reply, but not really. The issue is open that xml with a spreadsheet that already exists. i've got a lot of xml files, and foreach one it open the same spreadsheet.On my case is Deposit_Check_Template_OPEX.xlsx.